# Major issue with python return statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

function that finds the sum of all numbers up to (and including) N that are multiples of either x or y.

I tried putting the return statement at different indentations,still no hope

```
def multipleSum(N,x,y):
    z=0
    a=0
    for i in range(0,N+1):
        if i%x==0:
            z=z+i   
        elif i%y==0:
            a=a+i
        else:
            s=z+a
    return s
```

**test case:**

> multipleSum(10, 2, 3) ==42

expected result is **42**, actual result is **15**

Comment: Why do you think the return statement is the problem? It seems obvious to me that the logic is wrong in some other way. Please [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask], and please start with the [tour] if you haven't taken it already. (I know this is an old question, I'm just commenting to justify closure, or in case any newbies come around, they can understand what's wrong in more detail.)

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
def multipleSum(N,x,y):
    total=0
    for i in range(N+1): # No need to mention 0(zero), as range starts from '0'
        if i % x == 0 or i % y == 0: # No need to use if and elif, better to use 'or' instead
            total+=i
    return total
```

**One more way:**

```
def multipleSum(N,x,y):
    return sum(map(lambda v: v if v%x==0 or v%y==0 else 0, range(N+1)))
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> multipleSum(10, 2, 3)
42
```